# jQuery Mobile how to refresh a page with list

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, jquery-mobile, refresh

I'm developing a simple website using Java Struts2 and jQuery Mobile, where I have an options page which has a link to a page with a nested list.

The navigation is as simple as clicking the list option (on the options page) and move to the that page with the list.

I'm able to draw the nested list exactly how I want it dynamically on the JSP, however the list content will keep static even if something changes on the database.

The problem here is that I want to be able to refresh the list content when:

1. at least when I enter that list page from the options OR
2. when returning from the nested list screen to the main list screen OR
3. by using an explicit button on the list screen to refresh the content - or eventually a timer

How can I achieve this behavior? I don't know how/where to apply or invoke this piece of code from the jQuery Mobile documentation:

> $('ul').listview('refresh')

I appreciate any kind of help. Thanks.

Comment: What version of JQM are you using? The method to do this has changed quite a bit over the development of JQM.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is helpful for you, but with 1.0b3 there is a new event you can trigger to process HTML conversion to JQM-elements and classes. This works with mixed code aswell (new genereated elements and old JQM-elements): `$('#my_list_id').trigger( "create" );`

Answer (score 1):

The selector should be a selector that applies to the list you want to create (the 'ul' is generic) - so if your list is `id = 'bliss'` the selector and function would be `$('#bliss').listview('refresh')`, and you activate that based on context, i.e. on pageshow, click, etc.

For example, on [pageshow](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html) I think it would be something like this:

```
$('#optionScreen').live('pageshow',function(event, ui){
    $('#optionList').listview('refresh')
});
```

You want to make sure that method fires so the bind happens before the page is actually shown (the snippet above is adding the refresh to the pageshow event of the `#optionScreen` page)

Here's the page `div` that would hold the list:

```
<div data-role="page" data-url="optionScreen" id="optionScreen">
    <ul id="optionList" data-role="listview">
        <li>generated stuff</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

edit 2- you may want to look at this plug-in for what you're working on, it might even be a solution to what you're doing: https://github.com/hiroprotagonist/jquery.mobile.actionsheet (it's a modal dialog for setting options, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So "#optionScreen" show be the navigation hash generated by JQM?

Comment: I refined my answer to show the html code - but yes, #optionScreen would be the nav hash that jqm is appending to the url

Comment: Thaks. I've managed to bind to `pagebeforeshow` but the call to refresh my list `$('#list').listview('refresh');` wont do anything. I'm assuming this supposed to internally request and provide the list updated right?

Comment: In my case I'm building the lists on my JSP. Listview refresh should reload my JSP so the lists are built again on the JSP side? Or the only way is to make the refresh and use Javascript to build them?